# Ordinary differential equations "ode"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please help me to solve this inhomogeneous equation?

$y''(x)+xy'(x)+y(x)=g(x)$

where g only depends linearly on the approximation, in particular it will be a polynomial.

Let say $y(x)= y_{H}(x) +y_{p}(x)$
Where $y_{p}(x)$ is particular solution and $y_{H}(x)$ is linear combination of the fundamental solution. In the case that coefficients are constant we can use characteristic polynomial for finding fundamental solution but I don't know how can I find it in variable coefficients?!

Comment: What denotes $$g$$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it's a function

Comment: @user637300: I think Dr. Graubner meant which function is $g?$ Do you know what it is? If so, please edit the question to provide that information.

Comment: Well, changing the problem from $y''+xy+1=g$ to $y''+xy'+y=g$ is a *gigantic* change!!

Comment: @AdrianKeister  do you have any suggestions for solving this challenge?

Comment: @user637300: To be honest, I kind of lost interest after you changed the problem. If you wanted help on another problem, then make another post.

Comment: @AdrianKeister  I just typed wrong.

Comment: Well, this one's going to have Gaussians in it, and the imaginary error function. You need to type up more context, including the exact form of $g$, or the problem will be closed (can't have answers submitted) very shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous equation is
$$y_h''+xy_h'+y_h=0,$$
with solution 
$$y_h(x)=C_1e^{-x^2/2}+C_2e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt,$$
obtained from the Wolfram Development Platform. As for a particular solution, if $g(x)$ is a polynomial of order $n,$ then we can see that the LHS, given an ansatz of a polynomial of order $n,$ will also be a polynomial of order $n.$ Therefore, I would try $y_p$ as a polynomial of order $n$ and work out the coefficients by plugging in, once $g$ is known.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace Transform, one obtains (assuming g is a polynomial with constant coefficients):

$y(x) = e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} \,[a-i\;b\;\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\;erf(\frac{i\;x}{\sqrt{2}})+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^{\frac{k}{2}}\;e^{-\frac{\pi\,i}{2}(k+2)}}{k+1}g_{k}\,\gamma(\frac{k}{2}+1,-\frac{x^{2}}{2})]$

where $a = y(0)$, $b = y'(0)$, $g_{k}$ are the coefficients of the polynomial, $erf$ is the error function and $\gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function

Comment: can you solve it for me?

Comment: @user637300 the point of homework is to (at least try to) *do it yourself*

Comment: Yes I can give me a moment or 2

Comment: Solved -- see above.